# soul package does not work with user-defined language shorthands

Tags: babel, incompatibility, soul, shorthands

Using `\caps` from the `soul` package with user-defined language shorthands generates an error. However, it works fine with language shorthands defined by `babel` itself, e.g. by using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\useshorthands{"}
\defineshorthand{"~}{\textormath{\leavevmode\hbox{-}}{-}}
\usepackage{soul} 

\begin{document}
    \caps{LS"~2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: May I suggest to not use `\caps`, and use a real small caps font instead? This might even look better.

Comment: @mafp, I use `\caps` to increase spacing with normal capitals or small caps font.

Comment: Letter spacing of a small caps font could also be increased with `microtype`, if this is an option for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`soul` performs a little test to see if the german language has been loaded, so that the shorthand `"` is taken into account when parsing the string. Just add to the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\mdqoff}{}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also loading with `\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}` solves the problem.